# Scaling the image fully without losing its content

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, swift4

Im working on a project in swift where I use an xib file to load my header image. As of now only partially is visible in my image view. How can i over come this issue.

What I want is 
[image]

But what i get is this.

[image]

Once I set the content mood to aspect fit what i get is this.
[image]

This is my storyBoard
[image]
[image]

As you can see the "moon" all the way to right in screen is not in the picture. How can i scale this properly??

Comment: you are using `aspectFill` and you need to use `aspectFit`as contentMode for your `UIImageView`

Comment: didnt help to solve the issue

Comment: can you post the new result image? using aspectFit?

Comment: If content mode didn't solve your problem then constraints might be the problem. Your image view width might be greater than the width of the screen

Comment: Share your code (or storyboard design), how do you set this image?

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing image with below line

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

`UIEdgeInsetsMake` top left right bottom must be correct.

Comment: UIImage(named: "YOURImage")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))

Comment: @danu Swift is nothing just programming language

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the imageView and the image in equal ratio's that is if the size of the imageView would be 26:46(height:width) the image should follow the same ratio standards that is 13:23 or 52:92. You need to change the UIImageView as per the width/height to match the ratio of image. Stretching of the images is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please set Aspect ratio to imageView by looking image in preview app.
Once you open the image set image width same as width of UIImageView in xib, then accordingly height will be adjust in preview editor.

Now go to your xib file and set imageview height same as that of display in preview, then set imageView aspect ratio.

Make sure that you have given enough constraint to your imageView in xib.

In this way image will adjusted according to the different device sizes.
Make sure image width will not be less than maximum imageView width calculated from xib, imageview height will adjusted accordingly due to aspect ratio property.

Answer (score 0):

The main point to understand here is that it won't work for all the screens you have using 1 image.

Why: Designer gave you an image with 58 height and 375 width (width of iphone 8).

So there is a question how to show this image on iPhone SE and iPhone 8plus? And you have only 1 image for that. The Answer is that you can't make it pixel perfect with 1 image.

Solutions:

1. Ask the designer how he wants it too look like using 1 image for all the devices.
2. Ask the designer to make 3 different images for you.
3. Separate image and text. Ask for 1 image and make it `scaleFill` content mode and put a label for text on your own.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `scaleToFill` it will help

`AspectFill` scales the content to totally fill the view maintaining the aspect ratio AND `ScaleToFill` stretches the view to fill the available space without maintaining the aspect ratio

so, This can stretch your image but it will work

Comment: this will stretch my image but wouldnt solve the issue sir

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fit the given image without maintaining aspect ratio then simply use

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

but if you want to maintain the aspect ratio then you need to resize the image to fit the imageView. You can use below function and pass the imageView size and apply the returning image. Read more about it [here](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/)

```
extension UIImageView {

  func imageScaledToFit(_ size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let imageAspectRatio = self.size.width / self.size.height
    let canvasAspectRatio = size.width / size.height
    var resizeFactor: CGFloat

    if imageAspectRatio > canvasAspectRatio {        
       resizeFactor = size.width / self.size.width
    } else {
       resizeFactor = size.height / self.size.height
    }

    let scaledSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width * resizeFactor, height: self.size.height * resizeFactor)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: (size.width - scaledSize.width) / 2.0, y: (size.height - scaledSize.height) / 2.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: scaledSize))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return scaledImage 
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image.imageScaledToFit(imageView.bounds.size)
```